# Autoscaling persisted storage on stateful sets

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I don't think that there's even API for autoscaler to increase storage size of persisted disks in stateful sets, even if it's not advisable, even for something like mongodb. I guess that it would involve restarting the pod, too.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE you can scale up your storage limit in your **PersistentVolumeClaims** underlying your existing PeristsentVolume and it will dynamically resize your existing volume. After (manually) POD restart, it should by bound to the same pvc and data stored in resized PV.

Hope this help.

Please share with your experience.

Comment: So I should both tell it to scale when it needs to with PersistentVolumeClaims, but then also manually restart the pod? The storage isn't cheap enough to just assign a ridiculous amount from the start.

Comment: I just use locked-in provider that charges pennies for 10gb a month, and charges you for what you use, although of course, it might be crappy memory. With autoscaling everywhere else.

Comment: Hi, please take o look for [Persistent disk pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#total_cost). In GCP Persistent disks are charged for the amount of provisioned space per disk.
You can use also for example [Platform specific Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=ed370d70-9c38-4de3-a3ec-babf3c064f71) to predict - overall costs for your solution.
Please take o look also for [Cloud Storage Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing)

Comment: Won't beat provisioning 200gb, and being charged only for 10gb used.

Comment: It's not clear for me what do you mean. Please take a look [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#resizing-an-in-use-persistentvolumeclaim) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/) for Online File System Expansion.